# ts don't lint missed parameter with any type

Tags: typescript

```
type MyFunc = (init: any, description: string) => number

const fun: MyFunc = (init: any): number => +init
```

I found a strange phenomenon that typescript can't lint missed parameter correctly.

In this case, I defined two parameters in the type `Myfunc` while only passing in one in the real function `fun`. However, the IDE didn't show me an error about the missed parameter.

Could you tell me what's the causes?

Comment: What do you think the problem is? That implementation _does_ accept two parameters, it just ignores one of them, and the second parameter isn't unused in the definition because other implementations might use it. What did you expect the linter to take issue with?

Comment: The second one is not optional, it's not marked with a question mark. The linter should tell me the missed one which is not optional.

Comment: It's not optional **for the caller**. But again the implementation **does** accept the value, JavaScript itself doesn't really care how many parameters a function declares. Think about it: what happens if you now call `fun({}, "hello")`?

Comment: I understand what you mean now. I see a disaster if the implementation has an `any` type, there will be no lint at all.

Comment: What "disaster"? I also suspect you're saying "lint" where you mean "type checking", which is a different thing.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigCgJbN2AC4oBDZEAGigBMIBnVAJ1zGFwHtkT7gXkA5gEpMAPijJEAWwBGEJgFgAUMtRdeUAGYoScJGkw58hEuRBCSk2fLFQA1MeDLl25NgDkpd0IDcQA) on how the parameter is required for the caller but not the implementor. In fact a linter will actually ask you to remove the parameter if you are not using it in the function implementation.